# Typescript: string enum return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an enum defined like this :

```
export enum ViewSide {
    Left = 'left',
    Right = 'right'
}
```

But when I try to use it, it doesn't work as intended:

```
console.log(ViewSide); // return {0: "LEFT", 1: "RIGHT", LEFT: 0, RIGHT: 1}
console.log(ViewSide.Right); // return undefined instead of 'right'
console.log(ViewSide['Right']); // return undefined
```

I have used similar enums, but they works correctly and return the string.

Any idea ?

EDIT: Turns out it was just a cache problem. I had defined the enum without the string before, and it stayed like this for a while.

Comment: Can you replicate this on a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? I tried but works perfectly fine for me. Here, check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enum-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts) out

Comment: `console.log(ViewSide.FooBar)` will also print *undefined*. The problem is that you think it shouldn't be undefined. Accept what the console is telling you. Look at the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only explanation is that you have two enums with the same name and have imported the wrong one.

As you can see from the first `console.log` output, the other enum is defined like this:

```
export enum ViewSide {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
```

Comment: I thought the same, but there is only one enum of this type, and the import points right at it.

Comment: I would say that this is not possible, because it doesn't even return the data of the enum you defined.

Comment: yes, this `{0: "LEFT", 1: "RIGHT", LEFT: 0, RIGHT: 1}` should look like this `{ Left: "left", Right: "right" }` in the console. Check out SiddAjmera's stackblitz example

Comment: It will, if the correct enum is used. Check the console on [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20ViewSide%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Left%20%3D%20'left'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Right%20%3D%20'right'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20ViewSide2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20LEFT%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20RIGHT%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(ViewSide)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(ViewSide2)%3B): It does show the expected value for the enum the OP showed in his question. And it displays the output he showed us for the enum I described in my answer. That's the proof that he is not using the  enum he thinks

Comment: Move the *console.log* statements to the *same* file where you `export enum ViewSide`.

Comment: Turns out it was using the same enum, but an old definition of it (usual cache problem). Thanks for the answer, it put me on the right path.